# Python string -- swap positions in and out of parentheses

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
"Person One (Something inside here) Second Thing (another thing) OK (something else)"
```

I need to get the following:

```
"Something inside here (Person One) another thing (Second Thing) something else (OK)"
```

Currently I am doing it like:

```
inside_parens = []
for item in str.split("("):
    if not ")" in item:
        inside_parens.append(item)
    else:
        inside_parens.append(item.split("(")[0])
...
```

What would be a better approach?

Comment: I like your approach, it is very readable. Although I would split on `' ('`, and then add the space back in.

Comment: Regexes are your friend and worth learning. See Chris Morgan's answer.

Comment: Regular expressions are more frenemy than friend, but they're worth learning a bit of anyway, if only as a warning.

Comment: I assume "something inside here" may not contain parentheses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'Person One (Something inside here) Second Thing (another thing) OK (something else)'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(.*?) \((.*?)\)( ?)', r'\2 (\1)\3', s)
'Something inside here (Person One) another thing (Second Thing) something else (OK)'
```

The way in which whitespace needs to be not switched around makes it a tad uglier, but it's not a very bad regular expression.